# How to farmat /parse a markdown post from strapi in nuxt js

Tags: nuxt.js, markdown, strapi

I use strapi as CMS, and Nuxt in frontend. Now, when I get the posts from the api, and display them in the browser. the post body is not well formated. no paragraphs no headings ...

How can I transform the markdown to html using nuxt?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in editor in Strapi is a makrdown editor. The following packages can help you to format the markdown as HTML:

- [Marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked)
- [Markdown-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the content module (https://content.nuxtjs.org/) to display your post. It accepts Markdown, JSON, YAML, XML and CSV formats so if you can get your posts from Strapi parsed into one of these formats you can use it.

I recommend you to create a script to donwload your posts and save it locally into content folder (if possible) to reduce API requests, and then use de $content module in your pages:

```js
async asyncData({ $content }) {
  const postsList = await $content('yourFolderIntoContent')
    .fetch()
    .catch(() => {
      return []
    })

  return {
    postsList
  }
}
```

And your project structure must contain the directory /content/yourFolderIntoContent